# Core Data: Could not find member executeFetchRequest

Tags: objective-c, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Does anyone know why I'm getting the above error with the following code?

```
var moc:NSManagedObjectContext? = managedObjectContext!;
var req:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest();
var ent:NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: moc);
req.entity = ent;
var err:NSError? = nil;
var result = moc!.executeFetchRequest(req, error: err);
```

I've checked another SO ticket with this error message but can't figure it out. `result` is inferred from `moc!.executeFetchRequest` (as NSArray), the method signature seems correct so why can't it find `executeFetchRequest` on the `moc`?

Comment: I'm surprised that you aren't getting an error from `var moc:NSManagedObjectContext? = managedObjectContext!;` As an aside, you don't need `;` to terminate lines in Swift.

Comment: Why should there be an error for that line? managedObjectContext is from the lazily created property from the Core Data default code. I know I don't need semicolons but I like them. Makes code more readable in certain parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is misleading. You have to pass the *address* of the error variable:

```
var err:NSError? = nil
var result = moc!.executeFetchRequest(req, error: &err)
```

Also it seems unnecessary to me to define the local context variable as an optional,
and you don't have to specify the variable types if it can be implied from the
context. So your code could be simplified to

```
let moc = managedObjectContext!
let req = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
var err:NSError? = nil
let result = moc.executeFetchRequest(req, error: &err)
```

Comment: Doh, didn't see that! Thanks!

Comment: @Martin R  I write the code just as yours and I still get the same code. I hate swift!

Comment: @jerry_sjtu: I have copied the above code into a new Core Data project in Xcode 6.1, and it compiles without problems. What error message do you get exactly, and at what line?

Comment: Sorry, I just find that I don't unwrap the optional context.